# How to keep Excel Formatting When Exporting/Writing Excel Data To a CSV File?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

The following code reads Excel data and positions the data on a CSV file.

When the CSV file is created, formatted data on my Excel Sheet returns to it's pre formatted form.

For instance my data "mm/dd/yyy" -> 44067. Integers that have a leading "0", such as "01" -> 1. Decimal values such as "3.80" and or "7.00" -> "3.8" and "7".

```vb
Sub ExportCSV()
    Dim vArr, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim fNum As Long, fileName As String
    Dim sLine As String, sVal As String

    vArr = Worksheets("ImportFile").UsedRange.Value2

    fNum = FreeFile
    fileName = Environ$("Userprofile") & "\desktop\2225D_DH.txt"
    Open fileName For Output Lock Write As #fNum

    For x = LBound(vArr) + 1 To UBound(vArr)
        sLine = ""
        For y = LBound(vArr, 2) To UBound(vArr, 2)
        
            If IsInArray(y, Array(9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)) Then
                sVal = PadLeft(vArr(x, y), FieldLength(y))
            Else
                sVal = PadRight(vArr(x, y), FieldLength(y))
            End If
        
            sLine = sLine & sVal
        Next y
    
        Print #fNum, sLine
    Next x
    Close fNum

    Debug.Print "Saved file " & fileName
    MsgBox ("Your CSV File Is Ready!")
End Sub

Function FieldLength(col As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Select Case col
    Case 1: i = 9
    Case 2: i = 6
    Case 3: i = 6
    Case 4: i = 1
    Case 5: i = 2
    Case 6: i = 10
    Case 7: i = 4
    Case 8: i = 4
    Case 9: i = 9
    Case 10: i = 9
    Case 11: i = 9
    Case 12: i = 11
    Case 13: i = 11
    Case 14: i = 11
    Case 15: i = 9
    Case 16: i = 11
    Case 17: i = 1
    Case 18: i = 12
    Case 19: i = 6
    Case 20: i = 12
    Case 21: i = 12
    Case 22: i = 6
    Case 23: i = 12
    Case 24: i = 8
    Case 25: i = 12
    Case 26: i = 12
    Case 27: i = 12
    Case 28: i = 12
    Case 29: i = 1
    End Select

    FieldLength = i
End Function

Function PadLeft(str, num As Long) As String
    If Len(str) > num Then
        PadLeft = Left$(str & Space$(num), num)
    Else
        PadLeft = Space$(num - Len(str)) & str
    End If
End Function


Function PadRight(str, num As Long) As String
    PadRight = Left$(str & Space$(num), num)
End Function

Function IsInArray(searchVal, vArr) As Boolean
    Dim val
    For Each val In vArr
        If searchVal = val Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I don't see where you are inserting the separator. **However**, if you check the description of the `.Value2` property of the `Range` object, you will see the source of your date formatting issue.

Comment: Question is a little confusing, since this is not creating a CSV file - this would be a "fixed-width" text file...   However, if you want the formatted cell values you need to use the cells' `Text` property, but you cannot do this by reading the whole range into an array - you need to address each cell individually.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, sorry not a CSV, but a Text File. It is fixing the width of the data.

Comment: @Tim Williams, Where in this code would I write that text property so that I know it will keep the format.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should work.

As noted above, you need to use `Text` not `Value2` if you want the cell's formatted value.

```vb
Sub ExportCSV()

    Dim fNum As Long, fileName As String
    Dim sLine As String, sVal As String
    Dim rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long, v
    
    Set rng = Worksheets("ImportFile").UsedRange
    
    fNum = FreeFile
    fileName = Environ$("Userprofile") & "\desktop\2225D_DH.txt"
    Open fileName For Output Lock Write As #fNum
    
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        sLine = ""
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            v = rng.Cells(r, c).Text
            If IsInArray(c, Array(9, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)) Then
                sVal = PadLeft(v, FieldLength(c))
            Else
                sVal = PadRight(v, FieldLength(c))
            End If
            sLine = sLine & sVal
        Next c
        Print #fNum, sLine
    Next r
    
    Close fNum
    
    Debug.Print "Saved file " & fileName
    MsgBox ("Your file Is Ready!")
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not thank you enough. It worked out great. the only edit I made was the variables that closed out your for loops. Next c and Next r need to be switched. Thank you so much.